# Nginx : Exclude specific Name based Redirection rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, redirect

I have redirection rule in place on nginx config like,

```
location ~ ^/abc/(.*)  {
rewrite ^www.abc.com/web/primary/abc.html/$1;
}
```

but I need to exclude few directories of my redirection location for example,

```
location ~ ^/abc/ae
location ~ ^/abc/be
```

Those ae and be should not be redirected to above URL. can someone help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although achievable using `location` blocks, but you will need to make the blocks functional which could be complex for dynamic content.

The simplest approach would be a *negative lookahead assertion* in the regular expression.

In your example, the `location` block is not really necessary and your `rewrite` directive seems to be missing some white space. But something like this may work for you:

```
rewrite ^/abc/(?!ae|be)(.*)$ /foo/$1 last;
```

The `(?!` sequence begins a regular expression (`ae|be`) that **must not** be present at that point. See [this document](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for more.